# VNCServer will not start after editing /etc/sysconfig/vncservers

Tags: centos5, vnc, gnome

I'm running CentOS5.6 and am attempting to configure VNC.  I edited /etc/sysconfig/vncservers to read as follows:

```
VNCSERVERS="2:paul 3:sid"
VNCSERVERARGS[2]="-geometry 800x600"
VNCSERVERARGS[3]="-geometry 800x600"
```

When I try to start or stop vncserver, I receive the message

```
starting VNC server 2:paul [FAILED]
```

I created xstartup  as follows:

```
#!/bin/sh
unset SESSION_MANAGER
exec /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc
[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey
vncconfig -iconic &
xterm -geometry 80x24+10+10 -ls -title "$VNCDESKTOP Desktop" &

startx &
exec gnome-session &
```

What additional steps are required to successfully start vncserver and allow remote access to the GNOME desktop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you have a problem with the init script. Login as `paul` or `sid` and start a separate VNC session with `$ vncserver :2` or `$ vncserver :3`.

Comment: I logged in as both users and executed those commands.  xauth: creating new authority file /home/sid/.Xauthority  looks like default startup script was created and application started.  Should I now be able to VNC with either user?

Comment: Sure, it would work.

Comment: So, I tried to VNC into the server's IP address from 2 separate systems.  Both attempts were refused.  Do I need to restart vncserver service for this to take effect?

Comment: No. Make sure that you connect to port 5902 or 5903. Are you running `iptables`? If so, open this ports.

Comment: So, I opened several ports in the 5900 series using iptables.  I'm able to VNC but when I execute startx to start Gnome Desktop, I receive PAM Authentication failed, cannot start X server.

Comment: What? You execute `startx` after VNC? Did you uncomment 2 lines `unset SESSION_MANAGER` and `exec /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc` in `$HOME/.vnc/startup`?

Comment: I did uncomment those lines in xstartup.  Changed the latter to exec /usr/bin/gnome-session  and now just have a blank screen when I VNC.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1480/discussion-between-sidc-and-quanta)